# Proper way to switch Spring Data release train in Spring Boot Gradle Plugin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build a new up to date Spring Boot project but cannot find a way to switch Spring Data release train. We are using Elasticsearch with version 6.8 so I cannot just go with default dependencies provided by Spring Boot.

Spring Data Elasticsearch reference page tells that to use version 6.8 I need to use Moore release train https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions.

I have seen documentation for Maven https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent but same documentation for Gradle is lacking Release Train switch example https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation.

In short I have the following pieces in my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Moore-SR11'
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
}
```

Switching BOM in `dependencyManagement` section helps to switch `spring-data-elasticsearch` version from `4.0.5.RELEASE` to `3.2.11.RELEASE` but the version of `elasticsearch` is still taken as `7.6.2` from somewhere (`gradle dependencies` output):

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch -> 2.3.5.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.2.11.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.2.11.RELEASE
|         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26 -> 1.7.30
|         +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.10.8
|         +--- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:6.8.13 -> 7.6.2
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.53.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.53.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.53.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.53.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.53.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.53.Final
|         |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.53.Final
|         +--- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.8.13 -> 7.6.2
|         |    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

Is there a good example available or what am I missing here?

**UPDATE**: I found why I have version 7.6.2 taken for Elasticsearch. It is coming from `spring-boot-dependencies` project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L274.
Still looking for a way to override it.

Comment: in maven you'd need to set the `<properties><elasticsearch.version>6.8.x</elasticsearch.version></properties>` value. Not sure where to put this in gradle.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch `ext {
    set('elasticsearch.version', '6.8.8')
}` thank you for this hint

Answer (score 1):

With gradle and the `java-platform` plugin, we had some success by aligning dependencies version as described at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_version_alignment.html#sec:align-versions-unpublished

This overrides the version resolved for all `org.elasticsearch*` dependencies to 6.8.13

```
class ElasticSearchBomAlignmentRule implements ComponentMetadataRule {
  void execute(ComponentMetadataContext ctx) {
    ctx.details.with {
      // Force specific ES version
      if (id.group.startsWith("org.elasticsearch")) {
        // declare that Elastic Search modules all belong to the ES virtual platform
        belongsTo("org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-virtual-platform:6.8.13")
      }
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  components.all(ElasticSearchBomAlignmentRule)
  ...
```

In our experience, it was also needed to downgrade `spring-data-elasticsearch` but this is much easier and was done with a constraint in the platform

```
ext {
  ...
  // Downgrade below the boot integration for compatibility with es 6.8.X
  springDataEsVersion = '3.2.12.RELEASE'
  ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  constraints {
    api "org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:$springDataEsVersion"
    ...
  }
}
```